# How to proceed even if element not found or waiting in appium for android

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium

I am using **Appium (java)** for automating my **android** app.
Suppose I try to find a button (by *class/ id / accessibility*) and I don't get that - they either server keeps on searching for that particular id or throws exception.
Using `try- catch` is one option , but what incase if it still searching for element even after few seconds?
Kindly suggest the right approach to proceed

Comment: newcommandTime out =60 seconds , driver wont search after 60 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Create a method which will check element is available or not using your try-catch logic e.g

```
String elementID="something";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
    try{
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(elementID)));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log("INFO - "+elementID+" Element is Not Present");
        return false;
    }
return true;
```

If method returns true perform your operation or else assert it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution:

```
 public static Boolean elementExists(By selector) {
    List<MobileElement> elementlist = driver.findElements(selector);
    return (!elementlist.isEmpty());
}
```

The important part is using driver.findElement**s** which will return a list of elements found. Then simply check if the list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have wrapped it as a function **isElementPresent()** which is a boolean and returns true if element present.

```
public boolean isElementPresent(String identifier) throws IOException{

    MobileElement elementId = (MobileElement)driver.findElementById(identifier);

    Application_Log.info("Element found :- " , elementId);

    int totalSize = elementId.size();
    System.out.println(totalSize);

    if (totalSize!=0){

        System.out.println("Element found  : "+ elementId );

    }else{
        Application_Log.error("Element not found :- " + elementId);
        Assert.fail("Element not found :- " + elementId);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks karthick23. I'll try it and mark as answer if it works

Comment: The method size() is undefined for the type MobileElement in the line int totalSize=elementId.size().

Comment: @AnswerDroid, replace mobile element 2nd line of the function with this. List<MobileElement> totalElement= driver.findElementsById((identifier));

Comment: @AnswerDroid its the logic..try with what identifier you need. Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

`WebElement feedsCatItems = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)) .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("android.view.View")));`

You can use this. This waits for a particular element and then it moves. Here I am waiting for the view and it waits for 10 seconds.
This is pretty easy.